# Animation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the div to slide from left to right, and then back again from right left when it reaches the end of the browser using JavaScript.

```js
var imgObj = null;
var animate;

function init() {
  imgObj = document.getElementById('animate');
  imgObj.style.position = 'fixed';
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
  moveRight();
}

function moveRight() {

  imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 1 + '%';

  if (imgObj.style.left == '95%') {
    clearTimeout(animate)
    alert("i am here")
    moveLeft();
  }
  animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 20);
}

function moveLeft() {

  imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) - 1 + '%';

  if (imgObj.style.right == '95%') {
    clearTimeout(animate)
    alert('i am here2')
    moveRight();
  }
  animate = setTimeout(moveLeft, 20);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
#animate {
  width: 5%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a similar animation, started by the button.You should always use variables to change values and not just hardcorde values to elements. In this case pos is the variable that gets changed (pos++ and pos--) and then added to the style-property.

In your Code i think you never stop increasing the % value. So it gets stuck in a scenario where it does +1 -1 +1 -1 forever.

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
        alert("done");
      myMove2();
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
function myMove2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");   
  var pos = 100;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      alert("done2");
      myMove();
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.left = pos + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button> 
</p>


<div id ="myAnimation"></div>
```

Comment: any idea why it was getting stuck?

Comment: in my example you have the setInterval parameter, which defines that the function gets executed in the specified timeframes. Once the switch-point is reached it gets emptied with clearInterval(). That means in my Example the first function stops executing. In your example you start the 2nd function but never stop the first one from running. So you have both running simultaneously